# How to correctly trigger an Async process when receiving a message via MqttNet?

Tags: c#, async-await, delegates, mqttnet

We currently developing a set of .netCore console apps which reside on a remote server fed by mqtt message via MqttNet.

Upon receipt of messages in the mqttClient we pass these along to various registered Actions. The actions being key'd on the message topic.

```
public void StartClient()
    {
        mqttClient.ApplicationMessageReceived += (s, e) =>
        {
            var clientId = e.ClientId;
            var topic = e.ApplicationMessage.Topic;
            var payload = e.ApplicationMessage.ConvertPayloadToString();

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine($"ClientId: {clientId}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Topic: {topic}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Payload: {payload}");

            var action = actions[topic];

            action?.Invoke(payload);
        };

        mqttClient.StartAsync(options).Wait();
    }
```

An example `Action` could be:

```
public void StartupCompleted(string message)
    {
        IsInStartup = false;
    }
```

So when the message is received it sets a flag in one of the netCore apps.

For synchronous `Action`s this isn't causing an issue; however when we want to trigger an asynchronous or longer running process we start to see the netCore app crashing.

In our case we're trying to collect the mqttNet message and route them to specific EventHubs in Azure. For small numbers of message we can publish 1 by 1 direct to Azure and use a `Task.Run()` for them to be Fire and Forget; however as the number of messages increase Azure gets loaded too heavily and starts to reject the messages. As the publishing to Azure is wrapped in a `Task.Run()` we then loose the Exceptions and do not know if publishing succeeded or failed in order to schedule retries.

So in the higher level `ApplicationMessageReceived` method can we register Task's to be run when a Topic is received? Something like:

```
public void StartClient()
    {
        mqttClient.ApplicationMessageReceived += (s, e) =>
        {
            var clientId = e.ClientId;
            var topic = e.ApplicationMessage.Topic;
            var payload = e.ApplicationMessage.ConvertPayloadToString();

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine($"ClientId: {clientId}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Topic: {topic}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Payload: {payload}");

            var task = tasks[topic];

            await task?.Invoke(payload);
        };

        mqttClient.StartAsync(options).Wait();
    }
```

With correct syntax, etc. Or does this stall the ApplicationMessage processing until the Task has completed?

We do have two alternatives, neither of which is working particularly well...

1 - Force the async Azure functions to be synchronous as below, asyncContext is to ensure we receive any Exceptions; this is in a client wrapper for the EventHubProducerClient:

```
public void PublishEvents(string connectionString, IEnumerable<AzureEventMessage> azureEventMessages)
    {
        var task = Task.Run(() => AsyncContext.Run(() => PublishEventsAsync(connectionString, azureEventMessages)));
        task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
```

Where the Action is registered this triggered as a Fire and Forget:

```
public void PublishToAzure(string message)
{
    Task.Run(() => eventService.PublishToAzure(message));
}
```

2 - ensure the async code is present as long as possible, then in the Action have:

```
public void PublishToAzure(string message)
{
    Task.Run(async () => await eventService.PublishToAzure(message));
}
```

The additional problem here is that if the ApplicationMessageReceived handler needs to complete before the next message arrives we will drop messages... internal queue lengths are 250 messages, but even if we push that to 5000-10000 they will fill up over time.

Comment: Your data is coming in faster than going out.  You need do some timing analysis and find out the speed of coming in and speed of of going out.   Looks like there is an issue with the output speed.

Comment: The timing is related to the publishing out to Azure eventhub. However publishing to Azure is an async process which doesn't seem work very well with mqttNet Client receiving and processing messages.

Comment: You have a fixed size buffer so if data is coming in faster than going out you will overflow the buffer and get an exception.  You have to speed up the output or pack the or send multiple inputs in each output to reduce the overhead of the output.